# Starting batch file from Task scheduler point to C:\Windows\system32

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I want to start a service which requires to work open cmd console.

When I manually after login start a batch script from author of service (It cannot be closed - otherwise the service stop working)

```
@echo off
color 0
echo Preparation aplication Currenda Statistic Portal Version: 0.1 Beta (Raport) to start ...
echo Enter port, on which aplication will be available in web browser
set /p port="Enter port: "
echo Aplication will be started at: http://localhost:%port%
"libraries\bin\java.exe" -Xms2G -Xmx3G -jar raportgmin.jar --server.port=%port%
```

Evething works fine and the entered configuration (connections to database) saves in:

> D:\Statistic Portal\data\databases

But I want to start this service automatically so I changed the script like below

```
@echo off
color 0
echo Preparation aplication Currenda Statistic Portal Version: 0.1 Beta (Raport) to start ...

echo Aplication will be started at: http://localhost:9090
"D:\Statistic Portal\libraries\bin\java.exe" -Xms2G -Xmx3G -jar "D:\Statistic Portal\raportgmin.jar" --server.port=9090
```

and starts it from Schedule Task - the service works fine but the configuration file saves in:

> C:\Windows\system32\data\databases

**My question**

What I need to change in order to service start from schedule task and saves configuration files in

> > D:\Statistic Portal\data\databases

not in

> > C:\Windows\system32\data\databases

Comment: At some point you need to insert [`cd /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) in order to define the current working directory. Note that [`%~dp0.`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) refers to the patent directory of the batch script…

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!.

I edit batch file following your advice and everything seems to be work as I need and want.

One more time thank you.

```
@echo off
CD /D "D:\Statistic Portal"
color 0
"D:\Statistic Portal\libraries\bin\java.exe" -Xms2G -Xmx3G -jar raportgmin.jar --server.port=9090
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly have used something like the following idea, to define a title, your working directory, and console color all in one command:

```batch-file
@Start "Statistic Portal Version: 0.1 Beta (Raport)" /D "D:\Statistic Portal" "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe" /D /T:07 /C ""D:\Statistic Portal\libraries\bin\java.exe" -Xms2G -Xmx3G -jar raportgmin.jar --server.port=9090"
```

*Obviously you have the possibility of changing the `/C` option to `/K` to keep the window open on completion*